# How to Implement CSP for Ckeditor in Django

Tags: django, security, ckeditor

I'm not using CDN or any link for CKEditor but I have PIP installed it using pip install django-ckeditor. I have added all necessary CSPs and CKEditor configurations in settings.py file but CKEditor is not working in html.

In settings.py

```
CSP_DEFAULT_SRC = ("'self'", )
CSP_BASE_URI = ("'none'", )
CSP_FRAME_ANCESTORS = ("'none'", )
CSP_FORM_ACTION = ("'self'", )
CSP_STYLE_SRC = ("'self'", 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com','fonts.googleapis.com', 'stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com', 'getbootstrap.com')
CSP_SCRIPT_SRC = ("'nonce-value'", 'cdn.ckeditor.com','ajax.googleapis.com', 'stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com', 'code.jquery.com', 'unpkg.com', 'cdnjs.cloudflare.com', 'code.jquery.com', 'getbootstrap.com')
CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'", 'cdn.ckeditor.com' ,'cdn0.iconfinder.com', 'media.giphy.com','res.cloudinary.com')
CSP_FONT_SRC = ("'self'",'cdnjs.cloudflare.com','fonts.googleapis.com', 'fonts.gstatic.com')
CSP_INCLUDE_NONCE_IN = ("script-src", "style-src")
```

Another thing is my search functionlity no  longer works

Traceback
[The errors lies entirely in admin page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/oohTL.png)

Comment: would you be able to provide errors that you have in your console related to the CSP?

Comment: Would you like to send me the link of any project done with django-csp and ckeditor?.

Comment: That might be useful to see what should be the required directive, but it should be enough to also have the screenshot that you added. From the errors, it looks like you would have to extend your `img-src` directly with and enable `data:` value `CSP_IMG_SRC = ("'self'", 'data:', 'cdn.ckeditor.com' ,'cdn0.iconfinder.com', 'media.giphy.com','res.cloudinary.com')`

Comment: Did you find a solution?